# Bootstrap columns display different in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a issue with Bootstrap in Firefox. My columns are set correctly in Chrome, Opera and Safari, but not in Firefox.

I created ten boxes distributed in two rows. Five in each row. These boxes has classes `.col-sm-2` and `.col-xs-10`, besides a class called `.categoria`.

```
<div class="container categorias">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="img/corneta.png" alt="corneta">
                    <p>Novidades</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="img/contribua.png" alt="contribua">
                    <p>Contribua</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="img/nota.png" alt="nota">
                    <p>Sua Nota é Um Show</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="img/parceiros.png" alt="parceiros">
                    <p>Parceiros</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="img/projetos.png" alt="projetos">
                    <p>Projetos</p>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="img/historico.png" alt="historico">
                    <p>Histórico</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="img/objetivos.png" alt="objetivos">
                    <p>Objetivo, Missão, <br> Valores</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="img/relatorios.png" alt="balancetes">
                    <p>Balancetes</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="img/diretoria.png" alt="diretoria">
                    <p>Diretoria</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="img/estatuto.png" alt="estatuto">
                    <p>Estatuto</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

In Chrome, Opera and Safari, they appear correctly:

[Screenshoot from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL2Z6.png)

But in Firefox, it is completely irregular.

[Screeshoot from Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMkMS.png)

Note that I am using JQuery to set these boxes max-height so they will never have the height bigger than the width. I using the following code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    var columnWidth = $('.categoria').innerWidth();

    $('.categoria').css('max-height', columnWidth);

});
```

And here is the css:

```
.categoria{
    transition: background-color 0.5s linear, box-shadow 0.5s linear;
    background-color: #76C6C5;
    height: 140px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table;
}

.categoria img{
    padding-top: 15%;
    height: 50%;
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.categoria.col-sm-2 > p{
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 10px;    
}


@media(max-width: 768px){
    .categoria{
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 8em;
    }

    .categoria.col-sm-2 > p{
        font-size: 1.5em;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .categoria img{
        display: none;
    }

}
.col-xs-offset-1{
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

To be honest, I am not even sure if it is a problem with Bootstrap. But I don't know what else could be.

Comment: Looks like on firefox the size of the box is set by width and height of the image?

Comment: This does not address your height issue, but you should not be applying `padding` to `.col-xs-offset-1` as the offset already relies on padding / margins.  You can avoid wrapping your columns in the same class by simply adding `col-xs-offset-1` to the first column in each row.  Push/Offset are designed to be used alongside the column sizing, not as wrappers.

Comment: @RobertC, thanks. I going adjust that.

Comment: Try to add max-height to your class `.categoria img`

Comment: @matmik You are right. It seems the images are distorting the boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you should change display to table only when you don't want to show image :) that seems to resolve issue with uneven heights

CSS:

```
.categoria{
    transition: background-color 0.5s linear, box-shadow 0.5s linear;
    background-color: #76C6C5;
    height: 140px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}

.categoria img{
    padding-top: 15%;
    height: 50%;
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.categoria.col-sm-2 > p{
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 10px;    
}


@media(max-width: 768px){
    .categoria{
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 8em;
        display:table;
    }

    .categoria.col-sm-2 > p{
        font-size: 1.5em;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .categoria img{
        display: none;
    }

}
.col-xs-offset-1{
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="container categorias">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="http://kids.tate.org.uk/mygallery/kaimage/5140?size=LARGE" alt="corneta">
                    <p>Novidades</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="http://kids.tate.org.uk/mygallery/kaimage/5140?size=LARGE" alt="contribua">
                    <p>Contribua</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="http://kids.tate.org.uk/mygallery/kaimage/5140?size=LARGE" alt="nota">
                    <p>Sua Nota é Um Show</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="http://kids.tate.org.uk/mygallery/kaimage/5140?size=LARGE" alt="parceiros">
                    <p>Parceiros</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="http://kids.tate.org.uk/mygallery/kaimage/5140?size=LARGE" alt="projetos">
                    <p>Projetos</p>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="http://kids.tate.org.uk/mygallery/kaimage/5140?size=LARGE" alt="historico">
                    <p>Histórico</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="http://kids.tate.org.uk/mygallery/kaimage/5140?size=LARGE" alt="objetivos">
                    <p>Objetivo, Missão, <br> Valores</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="http://kids.tate.org.uk/mygallery/kaimage/5140?size=LARGE" alt="balancetes">
                    <p>Balancetes</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="http://kids.tate.org.uk/mygallery/kaimage/5140?size=LARGE" alt="diretoria">
                    <p>Diretoria</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categoria col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                    <img src="http://kids.tate.org.uk/mygallery/kaimage/5140?size=LARGE" alt="estatuto">
                    <p>Estatuto</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4aLmkmwm/2/)

Comment: You were right! I removed display: table and now works all right! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a constant value instead of a variable and intead of max-height property use height.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    // This value v
    var columnWidth = $('.categoria').innerWidth();
    columnWith = constant;    
    // This also change
    $('.categoria').css('height', columnWidth);    
});
```

If this doesn't change anything check all your tags matches. I can't tell you how many times it has happened to me when I don't close tags.
Hope I help.